# Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - Cannot prevent Cartesian results with Self Join

Tags: sql-server, self-join, cartesian-product

I have a table below - the table is populated with customer keys and roles. Each customer key can have multiple different roles associated with it, and I want to be able to identify a customer key with a specific list of roles. For example, I'd like to be able to identify all the accounts with roles ("A", "B", "C").

```
+--------------+------------+----+
| customer_key | sales_role |    |
+--------------+------------+----+
|          123 | A          |    |
|          123 | B          |    |
|          123 | C          |    |
|          456 | A          |    |
|          456 | B          |    |
|          789 | A          |    |
|          789 | B          |    |
|          789 | C          |    |
|          987 | A          |    |
|          987 | B          |    |
|          987 | C          |    |
|          987 | D          |    |
|          654 | E          |    |
|          654 | F          |    |
|              | Te<br />st | 45 |
+--------------+------------+----+
```

I've had success using the below query to identify accounts up to two roles:

```
SELECT 
c.customer_key
,COUNT(c.sales_role) as 'count'
FROM 
    table a
    INNER JOIN  table b ON a.customer_key=b.customer_key    
    RIGHT JOIN  table c ON c.customer_key=a.customer_key
WHERE 
    a.sales_role  = 'A' AND
    b.sales_role  = 'B' 
GROUP BY c.customer_key
HAVING 
    COUNT(c.sales_role) = 2
```

The above query will give me customer_key '456'.

However when I try and add more joins to identify more roles with the below query, I get Cartesian products.

```
SELECT 
e.customer_key
,COUNT(e.sales_role) as 'count'
FROM 
    table a
    INNER JOIN  table b ON a.customer_key=b.customer_key    
    INNER JOIN  table c ON a.customer_key=c.customer_key
    INNER JOIN  table d ON a.customer_key=d.customer_key
    RIGHT JOIN  table e ON e.customer_key=a.customer_key
WHERE 
    a.sales_role  = 'A' 
    AND b.sales_role  = 'B'    
    AND c.sales_role  = 'C' 


GROUP BY e.customer_key
HAVING 
    COUNT(e.sales_role) = 3
```

I'm not sure what else to try here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query, which does not require multiple connections, should do what you need:

```
SELECT 
a.customer_key
,COUNT(DISTINCT a.sales_role) as 'count'
FROM table a
WHERE a.sales_role  IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY a.customer_key
HAVING 
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.sales_role) = 2
```

When you need to check for A, B, and C, change the IN and HAVING statements as needed.

Note that if you need to return records that ONLY have the values you are looking for, you will need to modify the query to test for the existence of other roles, and exclude those. This can be done like this:

```
SELECT 
    a.customer_key
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT a.sales_role) as 'count'
FROM table a
WHERE a.sales_role  IN ('A', 'B')
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM table b
    WHERE b.customer_key = a.customer_key
    AND b.sales_role NOT IN ('A', 'B')
    )
GROUP BY a.customer_key
HAVING 
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.sales_role) = 2
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, this seems to have done the trick. Do you mind explaining the NOT EXISTS part of the query?

Comment: Certainly. Once you have identified that a specific customer_key value matches the sales roles you are looking for, the query inside the NOT EXISTS looks to see if there are any other sales roles assigned to that customer. The NOT EXISTS() returns TRUE if nothing is found in that query, and FALSE if any row exists that matches that query. You can read that like "If no rows are returned by this query, report TRUE, otherwise report FALSE".

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust below query, counting the combination sale_roles you want to count, give a try.

```
SELECT Customer_Key
    , SUM(CASE Sales_Role WHEN 'A' THEN 1
                         WHEN 'B' THEN 1
                         WHEN 'C' THEN 1
                          ELSE 0 END) CntABC
    , SUM(CASE Sales_Role WHEN 'A' THEN 1
                         WHEN 'B' THEN 1            
                          ELSE 0 END) CntAB
    , SUM(CASE Sales_Role WHEN 'E' THEN 1   
            ELSE 0 END) CntE
FROM table
GROUP BY Customer_Key
```